# Rails redirect issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, redirecttoaction, nested-routes

I have setup some simple associations in my rails app:

```
resources :properties do
 resources :units
end
```

After updating a unit:

'localhost:3000/properties/2/units/3/edit'

I want to be redirected back to the appropriate location.

after I click "Update" I am redirected back to:

'localhost:3000/units/3', but should go to 'localhost:3000/properties/2/units/3/'

In my units controller, I have:

```
if @unit.update_attributes(params[:unit])
    format.html { redirect_to(property_units_path(@property, @unit), :notice => 'Unit was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @unit.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

Is this the appropriate use in my redirect_to function?  I am still trying to become familiar with how the routes work but I feel like this should work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You should redirect to:

```
format.html { redirect_to(property_unit_path(@property, @unit), :notice => 'Unit was successfully updated.') }
```

Note that your must use the singular version of the routing helper method for this to work. For more details check the rails guide on [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).